# How to use stop_gradient in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm wondering how to use `stop_gradient` in tensorflow, and the documentation is not clear to me.

I'm currently using `stop_gradient` to produce the gradient of the loss function w.r.t. the word embeddings in a CBOW word2vec model. I want to just get the value, and not do backpropagation (as I'm generating adversarial examples).

Currently, I'm using the code:

```
lossGrad = gradients.gradients(loss, embed)[0]
real_grad = lossGrad.eval(feed_dict)
```

<s>But when I run this, it does the backpropogation anyway!</s> What am I doing wrong, and just as importantly, how can I fix this?

CLARIFICATION: To clarify by "backpropagation" I mean "calculating values and updating model parameters".

#### UPDATE

If I run the two lines above after the first training step, the I get a different loss after 100 training steps than when I don't run those two lines. I might be fundamentally misunderstanding something about Tensorflow.

I've tried setting using `set_random_seed` both in the beginning of the graph declaration and before each training step. The total loss is consistent between multiple runs, but not between including/excluding those two lines. So if it's not the RNG causing the disparity, and it's not unanticipated updating of the model parameters between training steps, do you have any idea what would cause this behavior?

#### SOLUTION

Welp, it's a bit late but here's how I solved it. I only wanted to optimize over some, but not all, variables. I thought that the way to prevent optimizing some variables would be to use `stop_grad` - but I never found a way to make that work. Maybe there is a way, but what worked for me was to adjust my `optimizer` to only optimize over a list of variables. So instead of:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=eta)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
```

I used:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=eta)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[variables to optimize over])
```

This prevented `opt` from updating the variables not in `var_list`. Hopefully it works for you, too!

Comment: Does `loss` (and hence `lossGrad`) depend on any input readers, or are all of the examples passed in using the `feed_dict`? (Is the `feed_dict` the same for the `lossGrad.eval(...)` and the training step?) What are the randomness-inducing ops in your graph, if any?

Comment: Nope, all examples are passed in through the `feed_dict`. The `feed_dict` is the same one as for the training step. The randomness-inducing ops are the initialization of the Variables `embeddings` and `nce_weights`. `embed` depends on `embeddings`, and loss depends on both `embeddings` and `nce_weights`. It's reproducible on the stock word2vec example from the tutorials.

Comment: I notice that the word2vec example uses a custom reader op (`word2vec.skipgram`), which is stateful. Are you sure that it isn't executing multiple times (despite feeding in the examples and labels), i.e. once in the training step and once when you fetch the gradient?

Another possibility: if it's difficult to track down the side-effect, you could modify the call to `session.run(train_op)` to compute the gradient in the same step.

Comment: My bad - I meant word2vec_basic. IIRC, this one doesn't use `word2vec.skipgram`. 
Modifying the call to `session.run(train_op)` works (yay!) for the gradient w.r.t. the fed inputs, but not if I want to use new inputs. Is there a way around this?

Comment: by "backpropagation" I mean "calculating values and updating model parameters". ==> backprop only calculates the gradients. Optimizer is what updates the parameters.

Answer (score 65):

`tf.stop_gradient` provides a way to **not compute gradient with respect to some variables during back-propagation**.

For example, in the code below, we have three variables, `w1`, `w2`, `w3` and input `x`. The loss is `square((x1.dot(w1) - x.dot(w2 * w3)))`. We want to minimize this loss wrt to `w1` but want to keep `w2` and `w3` fixed. To achieve this we can just put `tf.stop_gradient(tf.matmul(x, w2*w3))`.

In the figure below, I plotted how `w1`, `w2`, and `w3` from their initial values as the function of training iterations. It can be seen that `w2` and `w3` remain fixed while w1 changes until it becomes equal to `w2 * w3`.

An image showing that w1 only learns but not `w2` and `w3`:

[image: An image showing that w1 only learns but not w2 and w3]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w1 = tf.get_variable("w1", shape=[5, 1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable("w2", shape=[5, 1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
w3 = tf.get_variable("w3", shape=[5, 1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5], name="x")


a1 = tf.matmul(x, w1)
a2 = tf.matmul(x, w2*w3)
a2 = tf.stop_gradient(a2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a1 - a2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)
```

Comment: in `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)` you have to pass in [w1] (list of tensors the loss depends on), otherwise you get Error: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type

Answer (score 32):

[`tf. gradients(loss, embed)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) computes the partial derivative of the tensor `loss` with respect to the tensor `embed`. TensorFlow computes this partial derivative by backpropagation, so it is expected behavior that evaluating the result of `tf. gradients(...)` performs backpropagation. However, evaluating that tensor does not perform any variable updates, because the expression does not include any [assignment operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops#Variable_helper_functions).

[`tf.stop_gradient()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) is an operation that acts as the identity function in the forward direction but stops the accumulated gradient from flowing through that operator in the backward direction. It does not prevent backpropagation altogether, but instead prevents an individual tensor from contributing to the gradients that are computed for an expression. The [documentation for the operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) has more details about the operation, and when to use it.

Comment: So does this mean that `tf.gradients(loss, embed)[0].eval()` will not change any weights in the network? 

How could I go about computing this value with arbitrary inputs, without first running them on the network and doing backpropagation in the process?

Thanks for the quick replies, btw :)

Comment: That's correct - it just computes and returns the value of that gradient, and doesn't run any of the ops that update the weights. If you want to compute the gradients on arbitrary inputs, just supply a `feed_dict` to `eval()`.

(For clarity: I'm assuming that by "backpropagation" you mean "computing gradients **and** updating the model parameters.)

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I've added an update that to clarify the question in light of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for `tf.stop_gradient(op)`. It is really useful. I would rather move its paragraph to the top of your answer because this is what people will be looking for.

Comment: The link is broken for the stop gradient documentation

Comment: The links should be fixed now!