# In tensorflow how can I rescale gradient before it propagates to the next layer?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a gradient entering layer L1 from layer L2_1 and L2_2 at the same time, I need to rescale gradient `(L2_1 + L2_2)` before it enters L1 by `1/sqrt(2)`. How can I do this?

My network looks something like this:

```
                L2_1
               /    \
input -> L0 - L1     L_final
               \    /
                L2_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide L2_1 and L2_2 output by sqrt(2). That will rescale both activations and backprop. If you want to modify only backprop but not activations, you can use gradient replacement trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480182/419116)

Comment: `L2_1_t = 1/sqrt(2)*L2_1
L2_1_y = L2_1_t + tf.stop_gradient(L2_1 - L2_1_t)`
and
`L2_2_t = 1/sqrt(2)*L2_2
L2_2_y = L2_2_t + tf.stop_gradient(L2_2 - L2_2_t)`
and in the model construction code I would use `L2_1_y` and `L2_2_y` in place of `L2_1`, `L2_2` (as input to the next layer), is this right?

Comment: Looks right at first glance, but feel free to update this Q if you try it and it works, since others may hit have the same request