# Modifying ClassNLLCriterion in Torch

Tags: customization, torch, loss

I am new to Torch and I want to create a custom loss function in Torch which is a modification of [ClassNLLCriterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.ClassNLLCriterion). Concretely, ClassNLLCriterion loss is:

```
loss(x, class) = -x[class]
```

I want to modify this to be:

```
loss(x, class) = -x[class] + F(x)
```

where `F(x)` is a function that looks `x` up in a table (as a key) and outputs its value.

My question is, what's the correct way of implementing this custom criterion? The `updateOutput()` function seems straightforward, but how do I implement the `updateGradInput()` function?

Comment: what kind of table is `F`? It does not seem to be differentiable...

Comment: @fonfonx You are right, `F` is not differentiable. What's the best strategy in this case? Does it make sense to treat `F(x)` as a constant?

Comment: I don't know what ou wanna do with this `F`, and how much its values vary. I guess you could try to treat `F` as a constant but you somehow loose the utility of this `F` function I think. Maybe you could try to find a differentiable function approximating `F`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `F(x)` is not differentiable with respect to the network parameters, then you can't use it within the loss function. Differentiability is a necessary condition to perform gradient descent during backpropagation. See [Non-smooth and non-differentiable customized loss function tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752801/non-smooth-and-non-differentiable-customized-loss-function-tensorflow/44053871#44053871).