# TensorFlow: how to do python function with custom gradients without eval?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to write some custom TensorFlow functions in python (using `tf.py_func`) where I want to calculate both the results and the gradients in python.  I'm using the `gradient_override_map` trick (for example from from https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342 and [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/tensorflow-how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python/39921608#39921608)).

However, while the function in the forward direction gets a numpy array as an input, the function for the gradient gets `Tensor`s.  This is a problem, depending on when the function gets called, because there may not be a default session, and/or there may not be a feed_dict with all the required values yet (for example, in a tf.train optimizer).

How do I do a py_func where both the forward and backward functions get (and return) numpy arrays?

Sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sin_func(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def sin_grad_func(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0].eval()
    grad = grad.eval() # <--- this is what I'd like to avoid
    output_grad = np.cos(x) * grad
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(output_grad)

def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad_func=None):
    grad_name = 'PyFuncGrad_' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))
    tf.RegisterGradient(grad_name)(grad_func)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": grad_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    np_x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=1000, dtype=np.float32)
    x = tf.constant(np_x)
    y = py_func(sin_func,
                [x],
                [tf.float32],
                name='np_sin',
                grad_func=sin_grad_func)
    y = y[0]
    gr = tf.gradients(y, [x])
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    plt.plot(y.eval())
    plt.plot(gr[0].eval())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you want to include arbitrary Python code in your gradient function, the easiest solution is to create another `tf.py_func()` inside `sin_grad_func()`:

```
def sin_grad_func_impl(x, grad):
    return np.cos(x) * grad

def sin_grad_func(op, grad):
    return tf.py_func(sin_grad_func_impl, [x, grad], grad.dtype)
```