# How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

Sometimes the default [standard activations](https://keras.io/activations/) like ReLU, tanh, softmax, ... and the [advanced activations](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/) like LeakyReLU aren't enough. And it might also not be in [keras-contrib](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/keras-contrib).

How do you create your own activation function?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Credits to [this Github issue comment by Ritchie Ng](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4076#issue-183230193).

```
# Creating a model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Custom activation function
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects


def custom_activation(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) * 5) - 1

get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})

# Usage
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))
model.add(Activation(custom_activation, name='SpecialActivation'))
print(model.summary())
```

Please keep in mind that you have to import this function when you save and restore the model. See [the note of keras-contrib](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/keras-contrib#a-common-gotcha).

Comment: Also, it can be passed as a parameter to a layer, such as `model.add(Dense(10,activation=custom_activation))`

Comment: You might also be interested in [How can I `import *` from a module loaded with imp?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43932202/562769)

Comment: It might be useful to note that the preferred way to access the custom object pool in keras is through [custom_object_scope()](https://keras.io/utils/#custom_object_scope())

Comment: If its a custom activation function, does keras know how to back propagate that via differentiation. (like Theano)

Comment: Yes, Keras does autodifferenciation

Comment: Can I somehow provide my own derivative for the activation function, in case some modifications for numerical  stability are needed ?

Comment: @MartinThoma how does this `custom_activation()` function work? Since x is treated as a tensor, how does one understand the rank of the return value?

Comment: How can I write a function which does not use any of the existing function in Keras. For eg: x^2 - log (1/x). I understood the forward propagation is easy by using the method described above. But how will I write or integrate backpropagation along with it?

Comment: @Chinesh `custom_activation = lambda x: x**2 - K.log(1 / x)`

Comment: @MartinThoma I understood the part for forwarding propagation, I just want to know that I can I write a custom differentiation function. for eg: in the function, I mentioned I have something as for x < 0: function ouput ; for x > 0 function output + 10 x^2  ?

Comment: @MartinThoma Is there a good reference pointing out that Keras does auto differentiation?

Comment: Keras uses Tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/autodiff

Comment: Can you use as argument of the custom link function the output of terminal nodes?

Answer (score 36):

Slightly simpler than [Martin Thoma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915483/309334): you can just create a custom element-wise back-end function and use it as a parameter. You still need to import this function before loading your model.

```
from keras import backend as K

def custom_activation(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) * 5) - 1

model.add(Dense(32 , activation=custom_activation))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lambda` keyword or a [`Lambda`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) layer. Let's say your neural network *without activation* gives a bunch of `5`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((5, 5))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.Ones)
])

model.build(input_shape=x.shape)

model(x)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[5.],
       [5.],
       [5.],
       [5.],
       [5.]], dtype=float32)>
```

**And you want the activation function to divide by 5.** You can add a `Lambda` layer:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.Ones),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x/5)
])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Or use the lambda keyword in the `activation` argument:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 
                          kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.Ones, 
                          activation=lambda x: x/5)
])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you would like to add [`swish`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05941) or [`gelu`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08415) to keras, the previous methods are nice inline insertions. But you could also insert them in the set of keras activation functions, so that you call you custom fucntion as you would call `ReLU`. I tested this with keras 2.2.2 (any v2 would do). Append to this file `$HOME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/activations.py` the definition of your custom function (can be different for you python and anaconda version).

In keras internal:

```
$HOME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/activations.py

def swish(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(beta * x) * alpha *x)
```

Then in your python file:

```
$HOME/Documents/neural_nets.py

model = Sequential()
model.add(Activation('swish'))
```