# How can I `import *` from a module loaded with imp?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I currently work with keras and custom activation functions. I store those models as pickle and I would like to be able to load them again. Then I run into [this issue](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/keras-contrib#a-common-gotcha).

The problem is that the Python script which contains the custom activation function is given by path. I load this script via

```
import imp
model_module = imp.load_source('model', experiment_meta['model']['script_path'])
```

How can I "star import" (`import *`) in this case to make the loading of the trained model work?

### What I've tried

```
from model_module import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named model_module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer:

```
from model import *
```

Comment: In case you want to use this for keras, see [How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43915483/562769)