# Sampled_Softmax input parametrers

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am working on a Speaker recognition problem, I have very big number of classes so I need to use, tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss to speed up training time. The problem is I am using Keras with Tensorflow as Backend, but Keras doesnt implement Sampled_softmax so I need to use Tensorflow function, but its unclear which should be the inputs of the tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss() function.

My model and input are as below:

```python
from preprocess import *
import keras  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,AveragePooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import regularizers
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import metrics
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from importance_sampling.training import ImportanceTraining

epochs = 50
batch_size = 100
verbose = 1
labels= get_labels(big_numpy_files_path)
num_classes = len(labels)

#save_data_as_numpy_array(max_len = feature_dim_1, max_len2 = feature_dim_2,origin_path=data_set_path,destination_path=numpy_files_path)

#Get X & Y 
X_train, X_valid, X_test ,y_train,y_valid,y_test = get_x_y_data(split_ratio=0.8, random_state=42,maxsamples=20,path=big_numpy_files_path)
#reshape X for input into CNN
X_train, X_valid, X_test = reshape_prepare_for_input(X1=X_train, X2=X_valid, X3=X_test,channel=1)
#Dimensions
dim_1 = X_train.shape[1]
dim_2 = X_train.shape[2]
dim_3 = X_train.shape[3]

#one hot encoding of Y
y_train_hot = to_categorical(y_train)
y_valid_hot = to_categorical(y_valid)
y_test_hot = to_categorical(y_test)

#Model 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(6, 6),strides=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3])))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2, 2),strides=1, activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', use_bias=True,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',use_bias=True,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.02)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',use_bias=True,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.02)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy

model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer='adamax',metrics=['accuracy'])

earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=15, verbose=verbose, mode='auto')

model.fit(X_train, y_train_hot,batch_size=batch_size,callbacks=[earlystopping],epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid_hot))
```

If I want to replace the above loss function with Samled softmax, If I'm trying to do something like below, what should be the inputs give my above architecture and should I add tf.reduce_mean?

---

for more details on the code, is https://github.com/selimelawwa/Speaker_Verification

Comment: Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892380/how-can-i-use-tensorflows-sampled-softmax-loss-function-in-a-keras-model

Comment: hello sir, were you able to figure out on how to implement sampled softmax in keras? Please help me out a bit if were able to implement it.