# Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array TypeError when using sampled_softmax in tensorflow 2.4

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train a word embedding classifier using TF2.4 with Keras and using the `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`. However, when calling the `fit` method of the model, "Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array" TypeError occurs. Please help me to fix the error or with an alternative approach to do candidate sampling.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

 
TextVectorization = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization

class SampledSoftmaxLoss: #(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

  def __init__(self, model, n_classes):
    self.model = model
    output_layer = model.layers[-1]
    self.input = output_layer.input
    self.weights = output_layer.weights
    self.n_classes = n_classes


  def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    labels = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, -1)
    loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
        weights=self.weights[0],
        biases=self.weights[1],
        labels=labels,
        inputs=self.input,
        num_sampled = 3,
        num_classes = self.n_classes
    )
    return loss


max_features = 50  # Maximum vocab size.
max_len = 10  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
embedding_dims = 5

input_data = np.array([ 
    "Python Machine Learning",
    "Data Science from Scratch: First Principles with Python", 
    "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques for Building Intelligent Systems",
    "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists",
    "Vital Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: Best Practices to Improve and Optimize Machine Learning Systems and Algorithms",
    "Machine Learning in Python: Essential Techniques for Predictive Analysis",
    "Python Data Science Handbook: Essential Tools for Working with Data",
    "Introducing Data Science: Big Data, Machine Learning, and more, using Python tools",
    "Real-World Machine Learning"])

labels_one_hot = []
for i in range(len(input_data)):
    labels = np.random.randint(0, 6, max_features)
    labels[labels>1] = 1
    labels_one_hot.append(labels)

labels_one_hot = np.array(labels_one_hot)
 
# Create the text categorical encoding layer.
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
         max_tokens=max_features,
         output_mode='int',
         output_sequence_length=max_len)
 
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_dataset)
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
idxs = vectorize_layer(inp)
embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dims,input_length=max_len)(idxs)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embed)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(labels_one_hot.shape[1])(flat)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, out)

softmax = SampledSoftmaxLoss(model, labels_one_hot.shape[1])

model.compile('adam', loss=softmax.loss)
model.summary()
model.fit(input_data, labels_one_hot)
model.predict(input_data)
```

This is the log:

```py
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model/assets
Model: "model_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_84 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
text_vectorization_83 (TextV (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_83 (Embedding)     (None, 10, 5)             255       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_25 (Flatten)         (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_69 (Dense)             (None, 50)                2550      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,805
Trainable params: 2,805
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-87-c35b8d1321a1> in <module>()
    106 model.compile('adam', loss=softmax.loss)
    107 model.summary()
--> 108 model.fit(input_data, labels_one_hot)
    109 # Now, the model can map strings to integers, and you can add an embedding
    110 # layer to map these integers to learned embeddings.

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:238 __call__
        total_loss_metric_value, sample_weight=batch_dim)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:364 update_state  **
        sample_weight, values)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/weights_broadcast_ops.py:155 broadcast_weights
        values = ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name="values")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1540 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:339 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:265 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:283 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:435 make_tensor_proto
        values = np.asarray(values)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83 asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py:274 __array__
        'Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. '

    TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892380/how-can-i-use-tensorflows-sampled-softmax-loss-function-in-a-keras-model)? maybe relate to your problem

Comment: It may be due to the mix of inputs like numpy and Tensorflow ops datatype. You can follow this link and mentioned tutorials and check for the usage of `TextVectorization` in different solutions. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization#adapt

Comment: You can create a custom training loop using ```GradientTape()``` which should resolve your issue and prevent you from having to disable any features on tensorflow :)

Answer (score 35):

The error is caused by your custom loss function. You should disable TF eager execution mode.

`from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution`

`disable_eager_execution()`

Also, in `model.compile(...)` use `experimental_run_tf_function=False`

Comment: That's not a solution, in my case I'm running on GPU a model with LSTM layer, once I disable the eager execution, another error come's to be LSTM cannot use GPU it's not respecting the criteria

Comment: experimental_run_tf_function=False in model.compile(...)  can help without disable_eager_execution(). Did it make any difference for you?

Comment: I got the same issue. ````disable_eager_execution()```` works but after using it I get a precondition error.

Answer (score 3):

I added these two commands and solved the problem:

```py
import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution has saved me a bit of headache, but I am not certain why it works.
I am new to DL and I am just trying to be helpful.

Try:

```
del model
```

Before:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, out)
```

I understand I  could be wrong feel free to educate me, I am willing to learn :) .

Answer (score 0):

Disabling eager tensor worked for me.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score -4):

one of the main reasons for this error is that you may have installed Keras before TensorFlow.
Restart the kernel and you will be OK, if this is the case

Comment: does't work at all, I only installed Tensorflow, and use the kreas in the tensorflow package