# Tensorflowcustom loss function TypeError

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

i am implementing a custom loss function with tensorflow probability.
I want to use the model with its current weight iterations to make 30 predictions for each input and then use the mean of those and compare it to the y_true.
currently, i have the following code

```
def custom_Loss_Function(model):

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        a = model(model.inputs)
        for i in range(30):
                a = tf.concat([a, model(model.inputs)], 0)

        b = K.mean(a)
        b = tf.convert_to_tensor(b, dtype=tf.float64)
        return tf.reduce_mean(abs(y_true - b))
    return loss
```

and i get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

I tried to have b printed for a sanity check with

```
       tf.print(tf.shape(b))
```

but then i get the error

```
   TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <tf.Operation 'tf.print/PrintV2' type=PrintV2> with type Operation
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366442/cannot-convert-a-symbolic-keras-input-output-to-a-numpy-array-typeerror-when-usi) help to resolve your issue?