# "ValueError: Unknown activation: Activation" while trying to load a model with custom objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a model with two custom objects and am getting this error in the title.

This is where i import/define my functions, and where i allow keras to reference them by name.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.backend import sigmoid


def swish(x, beta=1):
    return x * sigmoid(beta * x)


get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})
get_custom_objects().update({'lrelu': LeakyReLU()})
```

I load the model with this part

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'swish': Activation(swish), 'lrelu': LeakyReLU()}, compile=False)
```

I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\trainer.py", line 102, in load_items
    model = load_model(data_loc + 'model.h5', custom_objects={'swish': Activation(swish), 'lrelu': LeakyReLU()}, compile=False)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 168, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 102, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 369, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 102, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 193, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 594, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 361, in __init__
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\activations.py", line 321, in get
    identifier, printable_module_name='activation')
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 180, in deserialize_keras_object
    config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 165, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown activation: Activation
```

Also might be worth noting that i am trying to save and load the model in different projects with different environments. Both are using tf 2.0.0 gpu. The imports should all be the same.

Comment: I saw this question before, did you delete your previous question?

Comment: Yea, i didn't get any answers so i wanted to repost and maybe add some more information

Comment: You should not do that, reposting or asking the same question more than once is not allowed. You can always edit your own questions.

Comment: Also I don't get why you are passing the activation as Activation(swish), you should just pass the function, not a layer.

Comment: I've seen that your supposed to wrap in an Activation Layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras

Comment: If you look at the first comment of that answer, you see that its not really necessary

Comment: I know you can pass directly to layer but because i am doing hyper parameter optimization i need to be able to pass by reference

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, the problem is literally that you are passing the activations in the wrong way.

Comment: I want to be able to do the following but for my custom activation  "model.add(Activation('tanh'))". I know this is possible because i add the reference by name and my custom activations work fine when i build the model. It's only when i load the model i get issues. I am following the guide here for swish https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swish-activation-function-in-keras/. The link i posted also shows that you should be reference the activation layer in the custom objects, not just a plain function

Comment: The tutorial is actually wrong, see my answer for details and the correct way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not blindly believe every tutorial in the internet. As I said in the comments, the problem is passing an activation function as a `Layer` (`Activation` to be precise), which works but it is not correct, as you get problems during model saving/loading:

```
def swish(x, beta = 1):
    return (x * K.sigmoid(beta * x))

get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1,), activation="swish"))
```

This code above is **NOT** the correct way, an activation inside a layer should not be another layer. With this code I get errors during `model.save` with `keras` and `tf.keras` in TensorFlow 1.14. The correct way is to:

```
def swish(x, beta = 1):
    return (x * K.sigmoid(beta * x))

get_custom_objects().update({'swish': swish})

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1,), activation="swish"))
```

Then you will be able to load and save the model correctly. If you need to add an activation as a layer, you should do:

```
model.add(Activation("swish"))
```

Which will also allow model save/load just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just use the following line of code and it works great!

```
activation=tf.nn.swish
```