# Do you need to define derivative function for custom activation function in tensorflow 2 keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I see in some places that you need to define the derivative function for your custom activation. Is this true? or is all you need to do just pass a tensorflow-compatible function to the wrapper and tensorflow.keras takes care of the rest?

Ie.

```
def my_actv(x):
    return x * x

model.add(Activation(my_actv))
```

Comment: You don't have to implement a derivative of the activation function. However, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)

Comment: I have seen that answer. What are you telling me to look at and why do some sources mention define the derivative function?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative needs to be defined if your function is not differentiable at every point. For example, `relu` is not differentiable at zero.