# Create custom activation function in keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, activation-function

I want to write a custom activation function with keras.backend for last dense of LSTM like this:

```
def customactivation(x):
    if x <= 0.5:
        return 0
    else :
        return 1



model.add(Dense(1, activation=customactivation))
```

what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)

Answer (score 0):

This function is not differentiable and will be useless for training unless you know what you're doing. You will get the error "An operation has None for gradient"

That said:

```
def customactivation(x):
    return K.cast(K.greater(x, 0.5), K.floatx())
```

Comment: yeah I used this but it gave me this error: ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

Comment: Yes, exactly what was expected.

Comment: after add this: `get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})` , it works! (it was mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras) )