# How to train and optimised my neural network

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I want to implement perceptron with python and ı use following equations, but how can ı set bias and how to update it.

You can click the links below to see the formulas.

[f(x) and σ(·) is a custom activation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEVYP.png)

where x is a D dimensional input vector, w is a D dimensional weight vector and b is a scalar

[The classification rule for the classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hOEM.png)

[loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FSdP.png)

I use back propagation algorithm to train perceptron

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Keras and create custom functions with it, it is a really user-friendly framework, here are some links to help you:

[How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)

http://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models

If you want to do it in plain Python (I wouldn't recommend), I would write all the derivatives to clarify my mind on how to do it.

Comment: Could you please write derivatives?

Comment: Do you want the derivative of the bias?

Comment: If you want a mathematical point of view of this question, it is better to ask it in https://math.stackexchange.com/. Stack overflow is more about implementation.