# How to define a modified leaky ReLU - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

I would like to use the leaky-ReLu function with minimization rather than maximization as my activation for a dense layer. In other words, I want my activation to be `f(x) = min{x, \alpha x }`. I first define a method as shown below.

```
def new_leaky_relu(x, alpha):
    part_1 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(0.0, x), dtype='float32')   
    part_2 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(x, 0.0), dtype='float32') 
    return (part_1*x) + (x*part_2*k)
```

When I test it on a simple model, I do receive an error.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(124,))])  
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation=new_leaky_relu(alpha=0.1)))
```

```
new_leaky_relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

How can I ensure that it is an activation function and I don't have to pass the input during compiling the model? Also, is the way that I constructed my activation function efficiently, or is there a better way?

I also used the suggestions shared in another post. See [How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)

```
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation
get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(new_leaky_relu)})

model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(124,))])  
model.add((tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,Activation(new_leaky_relu(alpha=0.1))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

def custom_leaky_relu(alpha=0.0):        
    def new_leaky_relu(x):
        part_1 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(0.0, x), dtype='float32')   
        part_2 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(x, 0.0), dtype='float32') 
        return (part_1*x) + (x*part_2) 
    return new_leaky_relu

model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(124,))])  
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=custom_leaky_relu(alpha=0.1)))
```