# How to use numpy functions on a keras tensor in the loss function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras with TensorFlow backend to build and run a neural network. I need to use a numpy function on my output tensor in the loss function. More specifically, my loss function involves finding nearest neighbors, and I need to use the Keras functionality for [ckdTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) for this purpose. I have tried converting my output tensor to a numpy array using `K.eval()`. However, this throws an `InvalidArgument` error when I try to compile the model, I believe, since you can't run `eval()` on a symbolic variable.

Here's a toy code snippet that reproduces this error.

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def loss(y_true, y_pred):

    y_pred_numpy = K.eval(y_pred)
    # perform some numpy operations on y_pred_numpy
    return K.constant(0)

''' Model '''

input_shape = (10,10,10,3)
train_images = np.zeros((1,10,10,10,3))
train_labels = np.zeros((1,1,1,1,3))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(3000, use_bias=True, bias_initializer='zeros'))
model.add(Reshape((10,10,10,3)))
model.summary()

opt = Adam(lr=1E-4)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss)
```

The above gives the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'flatten_3_input' with dtype float
     [[Node: flatten_3_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: reshape_3/Reshape/_11 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_20_reshape_3/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

How then do I work with Keras tensors without having to rewrite (complex) numpy functionality using Keras?

Comment: Is it really a problem in the loss function??? Have you tried compiling with `loss='mse'`? -- Even though, I'm not sure keras will accept numpy operations with the tensors. :(

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow) already?

Answer (score 2):

The direct using of this `numpy` function is impossible - as it's not implemented in neither `Tensorflow` nor `Theano`. Moreover - there is no a direct correspondence between `tensors` and `arrays`. `Tensors` should be understood as an algebraic variables whereas `numpy` arrays as numbers. `tensor` is an abstract thing and applying a `numpy` functions to it is usually impossible.

But you could still try to reimplement this function on your own using [`keras.backend`](https://keras.io/backend/) functions. Then you'll use the valid `tensor` operations and no problem should be raised.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/py_func or https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function provides a way to use functions that transform numpy arrays into numpy arrays on tensors.