# Tensorflow - calculate euclidean distance for RBF Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, radial

I have problem with implementation of RBF Network in Tensorflow. I need to calculate Euclidean Distance between x and centroids (from definition of RBF newtork). I wroted this code:

```
    x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

    # Create variables for NN layers
    A1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3, first_layer_nodes]))  # input -> first layer nodes
    A2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[first_layer_nodes, 1]))  # first_layer nodes -> sum node
    c = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[first_layer_nodes]))  # centroids

    # Declare NN
    inputs_with_weights = tf.matmul(x_data, A1)
    print(inputs_with_weights)
    # euclid_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.subtract(inputs_with_weights, c), 2)))
    euclid_dist = tf.norm(inputs_with_weights - c, ord='euclidean')
    print(euclid_dist)
    first_output = tf_gaussian_function(euclid_dist)
    print(first_output)
```

final_output = tf.matmul(first_output, A2)

But i is problem like this:

```
E:\#PROJEKTY\#PROGRAMOWANIE\AI-Project>python Iris.py
2018-04-27 00:49:37.800684: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("norm/Squeeze:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
Tensor("gaussian_function:0", dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
    target_list, status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix
         [[Node: MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](gaussian_function, Variable_1/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Iris.py", line 144, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_data: x_d, y_target: y_d})
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix
         [[Node: MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](gaussian_function, Variable_1/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul_1', defined at:
  File "Iris.py", line 124, in <module>
    final_output = tf.matmul(first_output, A2)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2064, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 2790, in _mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): In[0] is not a matrix
         [[Node: MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](gaussian_function, Variable_1/read)]]
```

If i try put any value to axis it stuck at:

```
E:\#PROJEKTY\#PROGRAMOWANIE\AI-Project>python Iris.py
2018-04-27 00:53:15.388129: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 686, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions. for 'norm/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [?,1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <2>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Iris.py", line 120, in <module>
    euclid_dist = tf.norm(inputs_with_weights - c, axis = 2, ord='euclidean')
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\linalg_ops.py", line 552, in norm
    tensor * math_ops.conj(tensor), axis, keepdims=True))
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1373, in reduce_sum
    name=name))
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 5436, in _sum
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3273, in create_op
    compute_device=compute_device)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3313, in _create_op_helper
    set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2501, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    return _set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2474, in _set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2404, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 627, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    require_shape_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Szatku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 691, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions. for 'norm/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [?,1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <2>.
```

I have no idea how to correct code. Can someone helps me?

EDIT: Gaussian Implementation:

```
def gaussian_function(input_layer):
    initial = math.exp(-SC*math.pow(input_layer, 2))
    return initial


np_gaussian_function = np.vectorize(gaussian_function)


def d_gaussian_function(input_layer):
    initial = -2*SC*input_layer * math.exp(-SC * math.pow(input_layer, 2))
    return initial


np_d_gaussian_function = np.vectorize(d_gaussian_function)


def np_d_gaussian_function_32(input_layer):
    return np_d_gaussian_function(input_layer).astype(np.float32)


def tf_d_gaussian_function(input_layer, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "d_gaussian_function", [input_layer]) as name:
        y = tf.py_func(np_d_gaussian_function_32, [input_layer],[tf.float32], name=name, stateful=False)
    return y[0]


def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):
    rnd_name = 'PyFunGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)


def gaussian_function_grad(op, grad):
    input_variable = op.inputs[0]
    n_gr = tf_d_gaussian_function(input_variable)
    return grad * n_gr


def np_gaussian_function_32(input_layer):
    return np_gaussian_function(input_layer).astype(np.float32)


def tf_gaussian_function(input_layer, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "gaussian_function", [input_layer]) as name:
        y = py_func(np_gaussian_function_32, [input_layer], [tf.float32], name=name, grad=gaussian_function_grad)
    return y[0]
# end of defining activation function
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the first argument of

```
final_output = tf.matmul(first_output, A2)
```

is not a matrix. So `first_output` is not okay. It comes from the previous line:

```
first_output = tf_gaussian_function(euclid_dist)
```

So we'd need to review that function `tf_gaussian_function()` but that's not in the posted code. I've checked if it's a typo and it should be tf.gaussian_function() but there is no such a thing.

So please post the definition of the function `tf_gaussian_function()`.

---

So now that we have that, it turns out that you're trying to map the function `math.exp( -SC * math.pow( input_layer, 2 ) )` (generally called rho or ***ρ***) onto `euclid_dist`; I take that would be your *radial basis function*. Side note: looks like you're trying to do some serious heavy lifting by implementing your own gradient, and everything, going through `np.vectorize()` and all that. I'd suggest you implement something much simpler, like this code (untested):

```py
first_output = tf.exp( -SC * euclid_dist * euclid_dist )
```

(I use `x * x` instead of the equivalent `tf.pow( x, 2 )` because the first is more efficient.)
This should create its own gradient and take care of all you're trying to achieve. But anyway, you sound confident that your implementation works, which might very well be the case as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853863/problems-with-my-rbf-network-in-tensorflow); you can also double check if it yields the same results as this one-liner.

In terms of what `euclid_dist` is, [`tf.norm( x, ord = "euclidean", axis = None )`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) is returning the 2<sup>nd</sup> norm (or Euclidean norm, otherwise also known as the square root of the sum of squares), so that is definitely a scalar. (It does *exactly* what the commented out line above says: `euclid_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.subtract(inputs_with_weights, c), 2)))`.) Not sure what you're trying to achieve there? If you just want the squares of distances, then you should do it like this:

```py
euclid_dist = ( inputs_with_weights - c ) * ( inputs_with_weights - c )
```

But as far as I understand, in a radial basis function network first you apply the weights on the input, then comes the radial basis function, and only as a third step comes the Euclidean distance as the cost function, which might very well be a scalar.

If that line is your attempt to implement ***normalization*** for your RBF network, please note that the [normalization is generally done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network#Normalized) a bit differently. So your implementation could look more similar to this, if I catch your drift right:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np

x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

# Create variables for NN layers
first_layer_nodes = 5
A1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3, first_layer_nodes]))  # input -> first layer nodes
A2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[first_layer_nodes, 1]))  # first_layer nodes -> sum node
c = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[first_layer_nodes]))  # centroids

# Declare NN
SC = 1
def rho( distances ): return tf.exp( -SC * distances * distances )
def norm( x ): return x / tf.reduce_sum( x, axis = -1 )
inputs_with_weights = tf.matmul( x_data, A1 )
print(inputs_with_weights)
distances = inputs_with_weights - c
print( distances )
first_output = norm( rho( distances ) ) # tf_gaussian_function(distances) # 
print(first_output)
final_output = tf.matmul(first_output, A2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    r = sess.run( [ first_output, final_output ], feed_dict = {
                  x_data : np.array( [ [ 1.0, 2, 3 ] ] ) } )
    for v in r:
        print( v )
```

Outputs:

> Tensor("MatMul_15:0", shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
>   Tensor("sub_8:0", shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
>   Tensor("div_5:0", shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
>   [[4.4366708e-03 6.8647589e-04 5.9621310e-01 7.5066246e-06 3.9865622e-01]]
>   [[0.31285414]]

---

To respond to the comment, where you posted this code fragment:

```py
exp_list = []
for i in range(first_layer_nodes):
    euclid_distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(x_data, c[i, :])), 1)
    exp_list.append(tf.exp(-SC * euclid_distance))
phi = tf.transpose(tf.stack(exp_list))
```

this could be vectorized, taking advantage of implicit broadcasting on [`tf.subtract()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/subtract) with advanced indexing like this (untested):

```py
ed = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( tf.subtract( x_data[ None, ... ], c ) ), 2 )
phi = tf.transpose( tf.exp( -SC * ed ) )
```

Comment: I put code into edit of post. Rather is no problem w tf_gaussian_function(). Because if put the input_with_weights it works well (but of course there is no RBF network). The problem is in tf.norm which returns me scalar and have no idea what set to do correct operation for each node.

Comment: I think: distances = inputs_with_weights - c is incorrect - euclidean distance is : sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) in two dimensional case

Comment: You don't have an Y here! There are no two coordinates! Even the centroids, they have only one coordinate! Euclidean distance in one dimension is in fact ***abs(x2 - x1)***.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to yell, I just spent a LOT of time on this answer, and looks like I might have misunderstood your question, which made me frustrated. `c = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[first_layer_nodes]))` made me think each centroid has only one coordinate. Was I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. I do my network in bad way. Now i'm looking for some optimisation of this:
[link](https://gist.github.com/SzateX/d5ad41bbc355347342efc345b447b942)

Comment: Optimization in what sense? Do you want to rewrite the for loop and vectorize it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now process of computation is about 10 times slower

Comment: What is the exact error you get on which line? (I can't test it myself without the full code.)

Comment: Yes, if possible, that would be useful, if I can just run it and work on it until it runs properly.

Comment: Code: [link]https://gist.github.com/SzateX/caa71a6aa767b52a54d386248588358b   and Data: [link]https://gist.github.com/SzateX/07034a0c7c6643d2c83a76b3b0f3089c

Comment: Are you running this under Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I use Python 3.

Comment: Ok had a meeting in the meantime. So managed to run your code in colab, commented out the save operations. This version is different than the one posted at this [link](https://gist.github.com/SzateX/d5ad41bbc355347342efc345b447b942). `c` is set up differently, etc. Which one shall we work on?

Comment: The new version