# How to use my own activation function in tensorflow train API?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, activation-function

Can I define my own activation function and use it in the TensorFlow Train API, i.e. the high level API with pre-defined estimators like ***DNNClassifier***?

For example, I want to use this code but replace the activation function ***tf.nn.tanh*** with something my own:

```py
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=feature_columns,
  hidden_units=[5,10,5
  n_classes=3, 
  optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01,
                                              l1_regularization_strength=0.0001),
  activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `activation_fn` parameter in constructor? What particular custom function do you want to use?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that parameter. But what if I want to use some scaled or modified version of some functions other than what is available through tf.nn.<function> list? There are many types of bounded function in this world :)

Answer (score 1):

If your custom function can be expressed in terms of built-in tensorflow ops, then it's fairly straightforward. For example:

```py
DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
              ...,
              activation_fn=lambda x: 2*tf.nn.tanh(x)+3*tf.nn.relu(x)+1)
```

In general, `activation_fn` can be a callable that accepts a tensor of arbitrary shape (because it'll be applied after each layer). Tensorflow will be able to backpropagate through this expression without any problem.

However, if you want a completely new custom op, not expressible via existing ones, you'll have to register it and compute its gradient manually. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39921607/712995) for the details.