# Customized derivative for Keras when back propagation?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

This is related to [How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)

I have implemented my own cost function

```
import numpy as np
import math
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K

def custom_activation(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) *2-1 ) 

x_train=np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(200,2))

model=Sequential([
     Dense(20,input_shape=(2,)),
     Activation(custom_activation),
     Dense(2,),
     Activation('linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train,x_train,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1)
```

Instead of letting Keras automatically take the derivative of my approximation function, can I give it the derivative?

Please note that this is only an example. My real custom_activation is way more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `@tf.custom_gradient` decorator on your function and define a `grad(dy)` function inside it to be returned:

```
#works only with tensorflow
from keras.backend import tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_activation(x):
    #... do things ...

    def grad(dy):
        #... do things ...
        return dy * the_derivative(x)

    #... do things ...

    return result, grad #return the result and the gradient function
```

Adapted from: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient

---

I never used this in Keras, but if it doesn't work instantly, you can try a hack of putting this function inside a standard Keras function:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

layer = Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation(x))
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but it did not work. What do you mean by putting this function inside a standard Keras function? I added what you suggested "layer = Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation(x))" to the code, but the error is: NameError: name 'Lambda' is not defined.

Comment: It seems that you have to register your gradient. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient I don't understand it well. Can you help?

Comment: You have to import `Lambda` from `keras.layers`.

Comment: There are still issues. Please see this related post based on your answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223640/custom-activation-with-custom-gradient-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is pretty similar with this problem [how-to-define-the-derivative-of-a-custom-activation-function-in-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754639/how-to-define-the-derivative-of-a-custom-activation-function-in-keras). Accepted answer in that link is self-explanatory and useful information to utilize.

To be short, you can check [TF Add New Op.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op).