# Custom Activation with custom gradient does not work

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to write a code for a simple neural network training. The goal is to define a custom activation function and instead of letting Keras take the derivative of it automatically for the backpropagation, I make Keras use my custom gradient function for my custom activation:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
from keras.backend import tf
from keras import initializers
from keras.layers import Lambda

@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_activation(x):

    def grad(dy):
        return dy * 0

    result=(K.sigmoid(x) *2-1 )
    return result, grad 

x_train=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]]);

inputs = Input(shape=(2,))
output_1 = Dense(20, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(inputs)
layer = Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation)(output_1)
output_2 = Dense(2, activation='linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(layer)
model2 = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_2)

model2.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model2.fit(x_train,x_train,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1,shuffle=False)
```

Since the gradient has been defined to be zero, I expect that the loss does not change after all epochs. Here is the backtrace of the error I get:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/p/CE/mytest.py", line 43, in <module>
    layer = Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation)(output_1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 474, in __call__
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 656, in compute_output_shape
    return K.int_shape(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 593, in int_shape
    return tuple(x.get_shape().as_list())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

**Update:** I used Manoj Mohan's answer and now the code works. I expect to see unchanged loss among epochs since the gradient is defined to be zero. But, it does change. Why? Am I missing anything?

Example:

```
Epoch 1/20
2019-10-03 10:31:34.193232: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 68ms/step - loss: 8.3184 - val_loss: 13.7232
Epoch 2/20

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 496us/step - loss: 8.2783 - val_loss: 13.6368
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
layer = Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation)(output_1)
```

with

```
layer = Lambda(custom_activation)(output_1)
```

> I expect to see unchanged loss among epochs since the gradient is
>   defined to be zero. But, it does change. Why?

The gradient was updated to zero in an intermediate layer. So, the gradients will not flow backwards from there. But from the output till the intermediate layer, gradient will flow and weights will get updated. This modified architecture, will output constant loss across epochs.

```
inputs = Input(shape=(2,))
output_1 = Dense(20, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(inputs)
output_2 = Dense(2, activation='linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(output_1)
layer = Lambda(custom_activation)(output_2)  #should be last layer
model2 = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer)
```

Comment: Thanks. The code works now. But, there is a problem which is explained above (updated my question)

Comment: Thanks. Now, I get what's going on.  I have an alternative answer. Do you think if my answer is also right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this getting the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
from keras.backend import tf
from keras import initializers


@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_activation(x):
    result = (K.sigmoid(x) * 2 - 1)
    def grad(dy):
        grad=0;
        return dy * grad

    return result, grad



class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        return custom_activation(x)


x_train=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]]);  


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
output_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(inputs)
layer = CustomLayer()(output_1)
output_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(layer)
model2 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_2)

model2.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model2.fit(x_train,x_train,epochs=10,validation_split=0.1,shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since the gradient has been defined to be zero, I expect that the loss does not change after all epochs.

This is not true.

We know that neural networks update weights by backpropagation. Here, you add a Lambda layer between Dense1 and Dense2, which gives zero gradients. However, the gradients of Dense1 and Dense2 have it's own calculation.
Now let's walk through how gradients are calculated.
Here is our model:
[image]
The gradient of trainable variables A1 and A2 are calculated:
[image]
So, in backpropagation, only the layer before lambda has zero gradient. Dense2 layer's weights are updated every train step, so the loss keeps changing every train step.

here is code we can check:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter


class MyModel(Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        """we overwrite this method only for store gradient to Model"""
        data = data_adapter.expand_1d(data)
        x, y, sample_weight = data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(
                y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
        trainable_variables = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)

        # ------------store gradients to Model-----------
        self.gradients = gradients

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


class MyCallback(Callback):
    """use call back to print weight and gradient"""
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs):
        print(f'BATCH: {batch}, logs: {logs}')
        print('\tweights: ')
        for w in self.model.trainable_variables:
            print('\t', w.name, str(w.numpy().tolist())[:100], sep='\t')
        print('\tgradients:')
        for w in self.model.gradients:
            print('\t', str(w.numpy().tolist())[:100], sep='\t')


@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_activation(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return dy * 0

    result = (K.sigmoid(x) * 2 - 1)
    return result, grad


x_train = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]])
x_test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]])

inputs = Input(shape=(2,), name='input')
output_1 = Dense(20, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', name='dense1')(inputs)
layer = Lambda(custom_activation, name='labmda')(output_1)
output_2 = Dense(2, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', name='dense2')(layer)
model2 = MyModel(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_2)

model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', run_eagerly=True)
model2.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, x_test), callbacks=[MyCallback()])
```

which prints:

```
Epoch 1/5
BATCH: 0, logs: {'loss': 10.934327125549316}
    weights: 
        dense1/kernel:0 [[0.30160099267959595, 0.21219481527805328, -0.19230186939239502, 0.2667768597602844, -0.32661852240
        dense1/bias:0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        dense2/kernel:0 [[-0.2596375644207001, -0.6473211646080017], [-0.16478103399276733, 0.07469578087329865], [-0.363366
        dense2/bias:0   [0.0009999979520216584, 0.0009999993490055203]
    gradients:
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        [[-0.904313862323761, -2.2795515060424805], [1.0773898363113403, 2.780249834060669], [1.279122710227
        [-1.5587334632873535, -4.176692962646484]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 10.9343 - val_loss: 10.8812
Epoch 2/5
BATCH: 0, logs: {'loss': 10.881184577941895}
    weights: 
        dense1/kernel:0 [[0.30160099267959595, 0.21219481527805328, -0.19230186939239502, 0.2667768597602844, -0.32661852240
        dense1/bias:0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        dense2/kernel:0 [[-0.2586376965045929, -0.6463212370872498], [-0.16578088700771332, 0.0736958384513855], [-0.3643662
        dense2/bias:0   [0.001999844564124942, 0.0019999409560114145]
    gradients:
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        [[-0.8996896147727966, -2.2749271392822266], [1.0717072486877441, 2.7745633125305176], [1.2724075317
        [-1.5500969886779785, -4.168041706085205]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 10.8812 - val_loss: 10.8282
Epoch 3/5
BATCH: 0, logs: {'loss': 10.828204154968262}
    weights: 
        dense1/kernel:0 [[0.30160099267959595, 0.21219481527805328, -0.19230186939239502, 0.2667768597602844, -0.32661852240
        dense1/bias:0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        dense2/kernel:0 [[-0.2576380670070648, -0.6453213691711426], [-0.1667805165052414, 0.07269597798585892], [-0.3653658
        dense2/bias:0   [0.002999449148774147, 0.0029997979290783405]
    gradients:
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        [[-0.8950660824775696, -2.2703030109405518], [1.0660256147384644, 2.7688772678375244], [1.2656934261
        [-1.5414618253707886, -4.159391403198242]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 10.8282 - val_loss: 10.7754
Epoch 4/5
BATCH: 0, logs: {'loss': 10.775383949279785}
    weights: 
        dense1/kernel:0 [[0.30160099267959595, 0.21219481527805328, -0.19230186939239502, 0.2667768597602844, -0.32661852240
        dense1/bias:0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        dense2/kernel:0 [[-0.256638765335083, -0.644321620464325], [-0.167779803276062, 0.07169625163078308], [-0.3663651347
        dense2/bias:0   [0.003998699132353067, 0.00399952195584774]
    gradients:
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        [[-0.8904435634613037, -2.265679121017456], [1.0603450536727905, 2.7631914615631104], [1.25898063182
        [-1.532828450202942, -4.150740623474121]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 10.7754 - val_loss: 10.7227
Epoch 5/5
BATCH: 0, logs: {'loss': 10.722732543945312}
    weights: 
        dense1/kernel:0 [[0.30160099267959595, 0.21219481527805328, -0.19230186939239502, 0.2667768597602844, -0.32661852240
        dense1/bias:0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        dense2/kernel:0 [[-0.2556398808956146, -0.6433220505714417], [-0.168778657913208, 0.07069668173789978], [-0.36736398
        dense2/bias:0   [0.004997501149773598, 0.004999083001166582]
    gradients:
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        [[-0.8858225345611572, -2.2610561847686768], [1.054666519165039, 2.7575063705444336], [1.25227022171
        [-1.524198055267334, -4.142091751098633]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 10.7227 - val_loss: 10.6702
```