# How to implement the code of this new activation function for CNN

Tags: tensorflow, relu

There are relu, leak relu and a new type of relu designed by myself, But I don't know how to implement it. I hope you can help me!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ4fd.jpg)

Comment: Click the link and you will see the picture.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow

Comment: @giser_yugang I read the answer, but I think it's still hard for me to achieve it.