# Is there a simple way to extend an existing activation function? My custom softmax function returns: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, softmax, activation-function

I want to implement an attempt to make softmax faster by using only the top k values in the vector.

For that I tried implementing a custom function for tensorflow to use in a model:

```py
def softmax_top_k(logits, k=10):
    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k, sorted=False)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(values)
    logits_shape = tf.shape(logits)
    return_value = tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, logits_shape, softmax)
    return_value = tf.convert_to_tensor(return_value, dtype=logits.dtype, name=logits.name)
    return return_value
```

I'm using the fashion mnist to test, whether that attempt is working:

```py
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# normalize the data
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

# split the training data into train and validate arrays (will be used later)
train_images, train_images_validate, train_labels, train_labels_validate = train_test_split(
    train_images, train_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=133742,
)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=softmax_top_k)
])


model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    train_images, train_labels,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(train_images_validate, train_labels_validate),
)

model_without_cnn.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model_without_cnn.fit(
    train_images, train_labels,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(train_images_validate, train_labels_validate),
)
```

But during the execution an error is occuring:

`ValueError: An operation has`None`for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable).`

I've found [this: (How to make a custom activation function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow#39921608), which explaines how to implement a completly custom activation function to tensorflow. But since this uses and expands softmax, I thought that the gradient should still be the same.

This is my first week of coding with python and tensorflow, therefore I don't have a good overview over all the internal implementations, yet.

Is there a simpler way to extend softmax into a new function, rather than implementing it from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using sparse tensors to make the tensor with "all zeros except softmaxed top-K values", use [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def softmax_top_k(logits, k=10):
    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k, sorted=False)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(values)
    logits_shape = tf.shape(logits)
    # Assuming that logits is 2D
    rows = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(logits_shape[0]), 1), [1, k])
    scatter_idx = tf.stack([rows, indices], axis=-1)
    return tf.scatter_nd(scatter_idx, softmax, logits_shape)
```

EDIT: Here is a slightly more complex version for tensors with an arbitrary number of dimensions. The code still requires that the number of dimensions is known at graph construction time, though.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def softmax_top_k(logits, k=10):
    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k, sorted=False)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(values)
    # Make nd indices
    logits_shape = tf.shape(logits)
    dims = [tf.range(logits_shape[i]) for i in range(logits_shape.shape.num_elements() - 1)]
    grid = tf.meshgrid(*dims, tf.range(k), indexing='ij')
    scatter_idx = tf.stack(grid[:-1] + [indices], axis=-1)
    return tf.scatter_nd(scatter_idx, softmax, logits_shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! 
What would I need to change this, to be able to accept a larger dimensional tensor than 2? Do I need to grab the last Layer of it to pass it into the 2D solution?

Comment: @JtheB I added a variation for arbitrary number of dimensions.