# What is the suitable activation function for determining odd and even numbers?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, activation-function

I want to create a neural network with tensorflow js just for learning purposes. It should determine if the input is odd or even and I think that can not be achieved with sigmoid or linear activations.

Is there a sin or cos function which is available in tf or if not, how to create a custom activation function?

Comment: create a NN for finding if a number is odd or even....why not! what you put as an input? here is the list of activation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations and here (in python tho) is a way to create your own activations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow

Comment: Just a note: If your input is binary then your output should be the least significant bit. No need for an activation function.

Comment: Hello. Supun.   what is output? An activation function is decided by an aim of your model.

Comment: Alexis my input is an integer. Training with a one d array of ints and ys are an array of 0s and 1s, indicating if odd or even...

Comment: so you have a single neuron in entrance... You might want to take another example for learning purposes

Comment: Do you think that it is imposible to do this with a simple NN?

Comment: What about %2 as a classifier? :)