# How to make a custom loss function+Gradient with Python in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, loss-function

This is generally about using tf.numpy_function in writing custom loss function. Where gradient of custom loss function must be provided manually as well.

Assume that a custom loss function with extra input arguments is written.

```
def custom_loss(self, targetPosition):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        loss_ = tf.numpy_function(self.forAllWrapped, [y_pred, targetPosition], tf.float32)
        return loss_;
    return loss
```

where loss function is written in a tf.numpy_function wrapper which gets the tensor values as Numpy arrays and sends it through GRPC to some C# code to calculate the loss.

```
def forAllWrapped(self, y_pred, targetPosition):
    result= np.empty((0,targetPosition.shape[1]), np.float)
    i=0
    numFKs = y_pred.shape[0]
    while i < numFKs :
        res_ =sres_=GET-INDIVIDUAL-LOSS-FROM-GRPC-METHOD(y_pred[i,],targetPosition[i,])
        result = np.append(result, self.trimResultFK(res_) , axis=0)
        i=i+1
    loss__ = K.mean(K.square(targetPosition - result), axis=1)
    return loss__.astype(tf.float32)
```

The loss calculation part works perfectly. But when I am gonna use my custom loss function, I am getting an error:

> Variable xxxxxx  has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

Due to usage of non-Tensorflow functions to calculate the loss value, then gradient is unknown to the optimizer and it cannot automatically derive it using [Automatic differentiation and gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/automatic_differentiation).
To solve this problem, I tried to implement custom gradient and attach it to my custom loss function based on [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921608). 
Here is the corresponding parts which attach the gradient using my version of self.numpy_function method:

```
def numpy_function(self, func, inp, dtype=tf.float32, grad=None):
    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))
    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.numpy_function(func, inp, dtype)
```

I have now 3 methods to override the gradient. First gradient is calculated in numpy domain (dummy outputs 1 and 0 for y_pred, targetPosition with the same shape as their numpy array shape):

```
def np_d_customGrad(self, y_pred, targetPosition):
    return np.ones((self.batch_size,2)).astype(np.float32),np.zeros((self.batch_size ,3 )).astype(np.float32)
```

Then it is wrapped for Tensorflow:

```
def tf_customGrad(self, y_pred, targetPosition):
    d_y_pred_, d_targetPosition_ = tf.numpy_function(self.np_d_customGrad,[y_pred, targetPosition],[tf.float32,tf.float32])
    return d_y_pred_, d_targetPosition_
```

and finally used to calculate gradient for two inputs of our custom loss function (y_pred,and targetPosition):

```
def customGrad(self, op, grad):
    y_pred = op.inputs[0]
    targetPosition = op.inputs[1]
    d_y_pred, d_targetPosition  = self.tf_customGrad(y_pred,targetPosition)
    return grad * d_y_pred , grad * d_targetPosition
```

This results in dimension error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1000,2] vs. [1000]

I have tried to return different shapes of zeros and ones in **np_d_customGrad** function. but it does not work. I assume that my function must return two gradient one per input parameters of custom loss function. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I have also tried to return the numpy array **result** instead of **loss__** values and use

```
return K.mean(K.square(targetPosition - actualPosition__), axis=1)
```

in *custom_loss* hoping that Tensorflow derives the gradient itself, but it could not.

Please note that I cannot implement the **GET-INDIVIDUAL-LOSS-FROM-GRPC-METHOD** method in python using TF as it takes months of work due to complexity.