# How to register a custom gradient for a operation composed of tf operations

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

More specifically I have a simple fprop that is a composition of tf operations.
I want to override the tensorflow gradient computation with my own gradient method using RegisterGradient.

What's wrong with this code?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

@ops.RegisterGradient("MyopGrad")
def frop_grad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0]
    return 0 * x  # zero out to see the difference:

def fprop(x):
    x = tf.sqrt(x)
    out = tf.maximum(x, .2)
    return out

a = tf.Variable(tf.constant([5., 4., 3., 2., 1.], dtype=tf.float32))
h = fprop(a)
h = tf.identity(h, name="Myop")
grad = tf.gradients(h, a)

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({'Myop': 'MyopGrad'}):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        result = sess.run(grad)

print(result[0])
```

I want to see all zeros in the print, but instead I am getting:

```
[ 0.2236068   0.25000003  0.28867513  0.35355341  0.5       ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define the op within the scope of `with g.gradient_override_map({'Myop': 'MyopGrad'})`

Also, you need to map `Identity` rather than the name `Myop` to your new gradient.

Here is the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

@ops.RegisterGradient("MyopGrad")
def frop_grad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0]
    return 0 * x  # zero out to see the difference:

def fprop(x):
    x = tf.sqrt(x)
    out = tf.maximum(x, .2)
    return out

a = tf.Variable(tf.constant([5., 4., 3., 2., 1.], dtype=tf.float32))
h = fprop(a)

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({'Identity': 'MyopGrad'}):
    h = tf.identity(h, name="Myop")
    grad = tf.gradients(h, a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    result = sess.run(grad)

print(result[0])
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: Doesn't this define a custom gradient function for the identity op and not the fprop function? If you do not multiply x by zero you won't see [5., 4., 3., 2., 1.] but instead you'll see the input to the identity() op.

Comment: @Milad that's probably why MZHm ignores the original gradient in MyopGrad, though I suspect there are very few practical use cases for doing that ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `tf.RegisterGradient()` for this purpose, I'm not sure if it is a proper solution. Because in the official documents https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient , it says:

> This decorator is only used when defining a new op type.

which means you need to define a new op written in C++ or wrapped  in `py_func`. I'm not totally sure if it can apply on the group of "tf op" you said.

---

However, You can also refer to the "trick" methods mentioned in this thread:

[How Can I Define Only the Gradient for a Tensorflow Subgraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456436/how-can-i-define-only-the-gradient-for-a-tensorflow-subgraph)

where you could combine `tf.stop_gradient()` and `tfgradient_override_map()` together to re-define the gradients for groups of operations

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54015702/3623290) answer (note that different questions might be satisfactorily answered by the same answer).