# Tensorflow: What gradients needed to be defined for custom operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

Although there are many references showing how to register a gradient, but I'm still not very clear what exactly kind of gradient need to be defined.

Some similar topics: 
[How to register a custom gradient for a operation composed of tf operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256517/how-to-register-a-custom-gradient-for-a-operation-composed-of-tf-operations)

[How Can I Define Only the Gradient for a Tensorflow Subgraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456436/how-can-i-define-only-the-gradient-for-a-tensorflow-subgraph)

---

Okay, here comes my question:

I have a forward function `y = f(A,B)`, where the size of each of them are:

```
y: (batch_size, m, n)
A: (batch_size, a, a)
B: (batch_size, b, b)
```

[image]

Suppose I can write down the mathematical partial derivatives of every element of y with respect every element of A and B.  `dy/dA, dy/dB`. My question is what should I return in the gradient function?

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("f")
def f_grad(op, grad):
    ...
    return ???, ???
```

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python) says that *The result of the gradient function must be a list of Tensor objects representing the gradients with respect to each input.*

It is very easy to understand the gradient to be defined when `y` is scalar and `A`, `B` are matrix. But when `y` is matrix and `A`, `B` are also matrix, what should that gradient be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) computes the gradient of the sum of each output tensor with respect to each value in the input tensors. A gradient operation receives the op for which you are computing the gradient, `op`, and the gradient accumulated at this point, `grad`. In your example, `grad` would be a tensor with the same shape as `y`, and each value would be the gradient of the corresponding value in `y` - that is, if `grad[0, 0] == 2`, it means that increasing `y[0, 0]` by 1 will increase the sum of the output tensor by 2 (I know, you probably are already clear on this). Now you have to compute the same thing for `A` and `B`. Let's say you figure out that increasing `A[2, 3]` by 1 will increase `y[0, 0]` by 3 and have no effect over any other value in `y`. That means that would increase the sum of the output value by 3 × 2 = 6, so the gradient for `A[2, 3]` would be 6.

As an example, let's take the gradient of the matrix multiplication (op `MatMul`), which you can find in [`tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.11.0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L1087-L1107):

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("MatMul")
def _MatMulGrad(op, grad):
  """Gradient for MatMul."""

  t_a = op.get_attr("transpose_a")
  t_b = op.get_attr("transpose_b")
  a = math_ops.conj(op.inputs[0])
  b = math_ops.conj(op.inputs[1])
  if not t_a and not t_b:
    grad_a = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(grad, b, transpose_b=True)
    grad_b = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(a, grad, transpose_a=True)
  elif not t_a and t_b:
    grad_a = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(grad, b)
    grad_b = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(grad, a, transpose_a=True)
  elif t_a and not t_b:
    grad_a = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(b, grad, transpose_b=True)
    grad_b = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(a, grad)
  elif t_a and t_b:
    grad_a = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(b, grad, transpose_a=True, transpose_b=True)
    grad_b = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(grad, a, transpose_a=True, transpose_b=True)
  return grad_a, grad_b
```

We will focus on the case where `transpose_a` and `transpose_b` are both `False`, and so we are in the first branch , `if not t_a and not t_b:` (also ignore the `conj`, which is meant for complex values). 'a' and 'b' are the operands here and, as said before, `grad` has the gradient of the sum of the output with respect to each value in the multiplication result. So how would things change if I increase `a[0, 0]` by one? Basically, each element in the first row of the product matrix would be increased by the values in the first row of `b`. So the gradient for `a[0, 0]` is the dot product of the first row of `b` and the first row of `grad` - that is, how much I would increase each output value multiplied by the accumulated gradient of each of these. If you think about it, the line `grad_a = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(grad, b, transpose_b=True)` is doing exactly that. `grad_a[0, 0]` will be the dot product of the first row of `grad` and the first row of `b` (because we are transposing `b` here), and, in general, `grad_a[i, j]` will be the dot product of the `i`-th row of `grad` and the `j`-th row of `b`. You can follow a similar reasoning for `grad_b` too.

---

EDIT:

As an example, see how [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) and the registered gradient relate to each other:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Import gradient registry to lookup gradient functions
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import _gradient_registry

# Gradient function for matrix multiplication
matmul_grad = _gradient_registry.lookup('MatMul')
# A matrix multiplication
a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]], dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Gradient of sum(c) wrt each element of a
grad_c_a_1, = tf.gradients(c, a)
# The same is obtained by backpropagating an all-ones matrix
grad_c_a_2, _ = matmul_grad(c.op, tf.ones_like(c))
# Multiply each element of c by itself, but stopping the gradients
# This should scale the gradients by the values of c
cc = c * tf.stop_gradient(c)
# Regular gradients computation
grad_cc_a_1, = tf.gradients(cc, a)
# Gradients function called with c as backpropagated gradients
grad_cc_a_2, _ = matmul_grad(c.op, c)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('a:')
    print(sess.run(a))
    print('b:')
    print(sess.run(b))
    print('c = a * b:')
    print(sess.run(c))
    print('tf.gradients(c, a)[0]:')
    print(sess.run(grad_c_a_1))
    print('matmul_grad(c.op, tf.ones_like(c))[0]:')
    print(sess.run(grad_c_a_2))
    print('tf.gradients(c * tf.stop_gradient(c), a)[0]:')
    print(sess.run(grad_cc_a_1))
    print('matmul_grad(c.op, c)[0]:')
    print(sess.run(grad_cc_a_2))
```

Output:

```
a:
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]]
b:
[[ 6.  7.  8.]
 [ 9. 10. 11.]]
c = a * b:
[[24. 27. 30.]
 [54. 61. 68.]]
tf.gradients(c, a)[0]:
[[21. 30.]
 [21. 30.]]
matmul_grad(c.op, tf.ones_like(c))[0]:
[[21. 30.]
 [21. 30.]]
tf.gradients(c * tf.stop_gradient(c), a)[0]:
[[ 573.  816.]
 [1295. 1844.]]
matmul_grad(c.op, c)[0]:
[[ 573.  816.]
 [1295. 1844.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean in the custom gradient function, I need to return the same results as what `tf.gradients` should give, of which each elements are summed partial derivatives of dy/dx?

Comment: @NathanExplosion Yes, that sounds right. I have added a snippet that (I hope) demonstrates how [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) and gradient functions relate to each other.

Comment: I tried `tf.gradients(c[0,0], a)`, it will return `dc[0,0]/da`. But if we defined the returned gradients as the summation of partial gradients, how could it derive an individual gradient?

Comment: @NathanExplosion In that case the flow goes like this. You have a slice operation that gives you a scalar, so you start the gradient computation with the scalar 1 as `dc[0,0]/dc[0,0]`. Then you compute `dc[0,0]/dc`, which is a matrix shaped like `c` with the gradient of `c[0,0]` wrt each element - so it is a matrix, `grad_c`, with all 0 except a 1 in the first value of the first row. Then you can get `dc[0,0]/da`, which is `(dc[0,0]/dc)*(dc/da)`. We saw it ended up being `grad_c * b.T`, so you get a matrix the size of `a` where the first row is the first column of `b` and all other rows are 0.