# Tensorflow: use different expression for forward and backward pass

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autodiff

I have a tensorflow expression where I want to use a different expression depending on whether I'm computing the forward or backward (gradient) pass. Specifically, I want to ignore the effects of some randomness (noise) added into the network during the backwards pass.

Here's a simplified example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = x**2
u = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(x), minval=0.9, maxval=1.1)
yu = y * u
z = tf.sqrt(yu)
g = tf.gradients(z, x)[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    yv, yuv, zv, gv = sess.run([y,yu,z,g], {x: [-2, -1, 1]})

print(yv)
print(yuv)
print(zv)
print(gv)
```

which outputs something like

```
[4. 1. 1.]
[4.1626534 0.9370764 1.0806011]
[2.0402582  0.96802706 1.0395197 ]
[-1.0201291  -0.96802706  1.0395197 ]
```

The last values here are the derivative of `z` with respect to `x`. I would like them to not include the multiplicative noise term `u`, i.e. they should consistently be `[-1, -1, 1]` for these input values of `x`.

Is there a way to do such a thing only using Python? I know I can make a custom operator in C and define a custom gradient for it, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Also, I'm hoping to use this as part of a Keras layer, so a Keras-based solution would be an alternative (i.e. if one could define a different expression for the forwards and backwards pass through a Keras layer). This does mean that just defining a second expression `z2 = tf.sqrt(y)` and calling `gradients` on that isn't a solution for me, though, because I don't know how I would put that in Keras (since in Keras, it will be part of a very long computational graph).

Comment: You can use tf.cond and a boolean variable (through a placeholder) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond

Comment: @ma3oun What would my condition be for `tf.cond`? How would I specify that I want one expression in the forward pass and the other for differentiation?

Comment: I just found the trick from Sergey Ioffe [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456436/how-can-i-define-only-the-gradient-for-a-tensorflow-subgraph/36480182#36480182). However, it doesn't seem to work for my situation here, and I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that Sergey Ioffe's trick, which you mentioned above, will only work if it's applied at the very end of the graph, right before the gradient computation.

I am assuming that you tried the following, which will *not* work:

```
yu_fixed = tf.stop_gradient(yu - y) + y
z = tf.sqrt(yu_fixed)
```

This still outputs random-tainted gradients.

To see why, let's follow along the gradient computation. Let's use `s` as shorthand for `tf.stop_gradient`. The way this works is that when TensorFlow needs to compute `s(expr)`, it just returns `expr`, but when it needs to compute the gradient of `s(expr)`, it returns 0.

We want to compute the gradient of `z = sqrt(s(yu - y) + y)`. Now, because
[image: \frac{\partial \sqrt{f(x)}}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{f(x)}} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}],
we find that the gradient of `z` contains both a term with the derivative of `s()`, but also a term containing `s()` itself. This latter term will not zero out the `s()` portion, so the computed derivative of `z` will depend (in some odd and incorrect way) on the value `yu`. This is why the above solution still contains randomness in the gradient.

As far as I can see, the only way to work around this is to apply Ioffe's trick as the last stage before the `tf.gradient`. In other words, if you do something like the following, you will get the expected result:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = x**2
u = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(x), minval=0.9, maxval=1.1)
yu = y * u
z = tf.sqrt(yu)
z_fixed = tf.stop_gradient(z - tf.sqrt(y)) + tf.sqrt(y)
g = tf.gradients(z_fixed, x)[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    yv, yuv, zv, gv = sess.run([y,yu,z_fixed,g], {x: [-2, -1, 1]})

print(yv)
print(yuv)
print(zv)
print(gv)
```

Output:

```
[ 4.  1.  1.]
[ 3.65438652  1.07519293  0.94398856]
[ 1.91164494  1.03691506  0.97159076]
[-1. -1.  1.]
```