# Keras Accuracy not changing for MNIST Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, mnist

I am new to Machine Learning and I was given the task of replicating the code from [Binarized Neural Networks: Training Neural Networks with Weights and
Activations Constrained to +1 or −1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02830.pdf)
. I would like to implement it on Keras.
I have written the code as shown below, however, the result obtained is stuck at 9.87%

BNN.ipynb

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization
from keras.constraints import min_max_norm
from keras.optimizers import SGD


from activations import binary_tanh as binary_tanh_op

#Load the data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

#one-hot encoding
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

#import to obtain _hard_tanh activation
def binary_tanh(x):
    return binary_tanh_op(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=784, activation=binary_tanh, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9,epsilon=0.000001)
model.add(Dense(128,activation=binary_tanh))
BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9,epsilon=0.000001)
model.add(Dense(64,activation=binary_tanh))
BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9,epsilon=0.000001)
model.add(Dense(10, activation=binary_tanh))

# Step 2: Build the Model

print(model.summary())
for layer in model.layers:
    h = layer.get_weights()
print(h)

opt = SGD(lr=0.000001)

# Step 3: Compile the Model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

# Step 4: Train the Model
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=100)
```

This is the activations.py file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import keras.backend as K


def round_through(x):
    '''Element-wise rounding to the closest integer with full gradient propagation.
    A trick from [Sergey Ioffe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36480182)
    '''
    rounded = K.round(x)
    return x + K.stop_gradient(rounded - x)


def _hard_sigmoid(x):
    '''Hard sigmoid different from the more conventional form (see definition of K.hard_sigmoid).

    # Reference:
    - [BinaryNet: Training Deep Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or -1, Courbariaux et al. 2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830}

    '''
    x = (0.5 * x) + 0.5
    return K.clip(x, 0, 1)


def binary_sigmoid(x):
    '''Binary hard sigmoid for training binarized neural network.

    # Reference:
    - [BinaryNet: Training Deep Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or -1, Courbariaux et al. 2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830}

    '''
    return round_through(_hard_sigmoid(x))


def binary_tanh(x):
    '''Binary hard sigmoid for training binarized neural network.
     The neurons' activations binarization function
     It behaves like the sign function during forward propagation
     And like:
        hard_tanh(x) = 2 * _hard_sigmoid(x) - 1 
        clear gradient when |x| > 1 during back propagation

    # Reference:
    - [BinaryNet: Training Deep Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or -1, Courbariaux et al. 2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830}

    '''
    return 2 * round_through(_hard_sigmoid(x)) - 1


def binarize(W, H=1):
    '''The weights' binarization function, 

    # Reference:
    - [BinaryNet: Training Deep Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or -1, Courbariaux et al. 2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830}

    '''
    # [-H, H] -> -H or H
    Wb = H * binary_tanh(W / H)
    return Wb


def _mean_abs(x, axis=None, keepdims=False):
    return K.stop_gradient(K.mean(K.abs(x), axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))


def xnorize(W, H=1., axis=None, keepdims=False):
    Wb = binarize(W, H)
```

I have tried changing my learning rate from 0.001 to 0.000001, my optimizer from Adam to SGD, added dropout rates, but my model is still stuck at 9.87%
[Training Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIARN.png)

Is there a way to improve the accuracy to 90+%?

Answer (score 2):

You have 10 different classes, so your accuracy of 9.xx% basically shows you that your neural network is guessing completely random.

That is a result of your learning rate value of `0.000001`, which is far too low to change any weights in a significant way in only 50 epochs. Change it to something like `0.001` and see what happens!

Comment: Improving my learning rate to 0.001 did not change anything. I am unsure whether it has to do with my activations.py, because when I use the inbuilt keras hard_sigmoid activation, I have achieved 99% for MLP

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation=binary_tanh))
```

The activation function worked, but I should not have added the activation function on the final layer.
It should be

```
model.add(Dense(10))
```