# Tensorflow: Copy variable-size matrix from one GPU to another and pretend copy has zero derivative

Tags: tensorflow

I have computed matrices of size `[None, 1024]` on each of two GPUs (call them "left GPU" and "right GPU"). The `None` represents the batch size. I want to copy the matrix from the right GPU to the left GPU (where it is treated as constant for differentiation purposes) and then multiply them:

```
result = tf.matmul(left_matrix, right_matrix_copied, transpose_b=True)
```

to obtain a square matrix of shape `[None, None]`. It's important that the matrix be square since I proceed to apply `tf.diag_part` to the matrix. (And in case you're wondering, I also use all the off-diagonal entries.)

I tried doing this by assigning the right matrix to a `tf.Variable` with `trainable=False` and then using `assign` with `validate_shape=False`, but I am still forced to specify the variable's initial shape statically (with no dimensions allowed to be `None`). And when I change the shape dynamically, the `tf.diag_part` op complains.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are `left_matrix` and `right_matrix` computed? If they are simply `tf.Tensor` values, you should be able to place the `tf.diag()` op on either GPU (by putting it in a `with tf.device(...):` block) and TensorFlow will take care of the copy.

Comment: @mrry: The key point is that each GPU needs to believe the value coming from the other GPU is constant, so that when I differentiate it will backpropagate separately on the two GPUs.

Comment: You could use `tf.stop_gradient()` (which is discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33729320)) to prevent the backpropagation between the GPUs.

Comment: `tf.stop_gradient()` appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!