# Neuron freezing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to implement **neurons freezing** in CNN for a deep learning research,
I tried to find any function in the Tensorflow docs, but I didn't find anything.
How can I freeze specific neuron when I implemented the layers with tf.nn.conv2d?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, you want to freeze Neurons in a tf.nn.conv2d convolution. While there is direct way of doing this in Tensorflow (as per my search), you could try slicing the Tensor and applying `tf.stop_gradient()` to it. Here is a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727935/how-to-use-stop-gradient-in-tensorflow) to give you an intuition on how to use `tf.stop_gradient()`

I haven't tested it, but according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) I think it should work.

Comment: I need to freeze neurons. When I create CNN with tf.nn.conv2d, each layer is a variable, but how can I freeze the neuron in the layer?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to freeze specific weights of the convolution filter or simply a filter and not the entire layer?

Answer (score 0):

A neuron in a dense neural network layer simply corresponds to a column in a weight matrix. You could therefore redefine your weight matrix as a concatenation of 2 parts/variables, one trainable and one not. Then you could either:

1. selectively pass only the trainable part in the `var_list` argument of the `minimize` function of your optimizer, or
2. Use `tf.stop_gradient` on the vector/column corresponding to the neuron you want to freeze.

The same concept could be used for convolutional layers, although in this case the definition of a "neuron" becomes unclear; still, you could freeze any column(s) of a convolutional kernel.