# Does tf.stop_gradient() help memory wise?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient

Does `tf.stop_gradient` actually help save GPU memory. I'm asking since some intermediate outputs of layers behind the stop_gradient might not have to be stored (which would've otherwise been necessary for gradient computation).

Comment: I believe it should do since that intermediate tensor will no longer be used for accumulating gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it saves GPU Memory. From the documentation of `tf.stop_gradient`, it states ***When building ops to compute gradients, this op prevents the contribution of its inputs to be taken into account.***

One more explanation about `tf.stop_gradient()`: It is an operation that acts as the `identity function` in the `forward direction`, but stops the accumulated `gradient` from flowing through that operator in the `backward direction`. It does not prevent `backpropagation` altogether, but instead prevents an individual tensor from contributing to the `gradients` that are computed for an expression.

It means that the Weights included in the Operation which is passed to `tf.stop_gradient` are not updated during Back Propagation.

Normally, during Back Propagation, Weights are updated using the Formula,

```
W(i+1) = W(i) - Learning Rate * Gradient
```

When we use `tf.stop_gradient`, the Weights which are passed as Inputs to this Op are maintained as Constants. Since the Computations during `Back Propagation` are reduced, **Memory Consumption also decreases**.

For more information regarding `tf.stop_gradient`, please refer [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient), [Abhishek's Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39356229/13465258), [mrry's Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33729320/13465258) and [this article](https://scelesticsiva.github.io/2018/01/22/stop-gradients/).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!